# MongoDB - Mongoose query findOneAndUpdate() doesn't update/duplicates the DB

Tags: mongodb, query, node.js

I am trying to save and update (upsert: true - creates the object if it doesn't exist) the result of the Web Api which contains multiple arrays of data to populate the stock chart. Each time I enter a symbol and click the "Get Quote" button it should fetch data from the web api, save/update it under the Child Schema in the database. For some reason it adds duplicate values. Is there a way to fix avoid duplicate values? Here is the code that I tried....

```
let curValueSchema = new parentSchemaSymbol()

      curValueSchema.symbol = curValue
      highLow.map(item => {
        curValueSchema.data.push(item)
      })
      const query = { symbol: `${curValue.toUpperCase()}` }
      const update = curValueSchema
      const options = { upsert: true, new: true }
      parentSchemaSymbol.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).then(doc => {
        console.log('Saved the symbol', doc)
        return res.send(highLow)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

As MongoDB Github collection documented with respect to Node.js MongoDB Driver API [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findAndModify) Find a document and update it in one atomic operation, requires a write lock for the duration of the operation.

**Syntax**

```
findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback)
```

// Example of a simple findOneAndUpdate operation

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  // Get the collection
  var col = db.collection('find_one_and_update');
  col.insertMany([{a:1, b:1}], {w:1}, function(err, r) {
    test.equal(null, err);
    test.equal(1, r.result.n);

    col.findOneAndUpdate({a:1}
      , {$set: {d:1}}
      , {
            projection: {b:1, d:1}
          , sort: {a:1}
          , returnOriginal: false
          , upsert: true
        }
      , function(err, r) {
        test.equal(null, err);
        test.equal(1, r.lastErrorObject.n);
        test.equal(1, r.value.b);
        test.equal(1, r.value.d);

        db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

// Example of a simple findOneAndUpdate operation using a Promise.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  // Get the collection
  var col = db.collection('find_one_and_update_with_promise');
  col.insertMany([{a:1, b:1}], {w:1}).then(function(r) {
    test.equal(1, r.result.n);

    col.findOneAndUpdate({a:1}
      , {$set: {d:1}}
      , {
            projection: {b:1, d:1}
          , sort: {a:1}
          , returnOriginal: false
          , upsert: true
        }
      ).then(function(r) {
        test.equal(1, r.lastErrorObject.n);
        test.equal(1, r.value.b);
        test.equal(1, r.value.d);

        db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

// Example of a simple findOneAndUpdate operation using a Generator and the co module.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  co = require('co');
  test = require('assert');

co(function*() {
  var db = yield MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
  // Get the collection
  var col = db.collection('find_one_and_update_with_generators');
  var r = yield col.insertMany([{a:1, b:1}], {w:1});
  test.equal(1, r.result.n);

  var r = yield col.findOneAndUpdate({a:1}
    , {$set: {d:1}}
    , {
          projection: {b:1, d:1}
        , sort: {a:1}
        , returnOriginal: false
        , upsert: true
      }
    );
  test.equal(1, r.lastErrorObject.n);
  test.equal(1, r.value.b);
  test.equal(1, r.value.d);

  db.close();
});
```

As Mongoosejs documented [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)

**Query.prototype.findOneAndUpdate()**
*Parameters*

- [query] «Object|Query»
- [doc] «Object»

[options] «Object»

- [options.rawResult] «Boolean» if true, returns the raw result from
  the MongoDB driver
- [options.strict] «Boolean|String» overwrites the schema's strict mode
  option
- [options.multipleCastError] «Boolean» by default, mongoose only
  returns the first error that occurred in casting the query. Turn on
  this option to aggregate all the cast errors.
- [options.lean] «Object» if truthy, mongoose will return the document
  as a plain JavaScript object rather than a mongoose document. See
  Query.lean().
- [callback] «Function» optional params are (error, doc), unless
  rawResult is used, in which case params are (error, writeOpResult)

*This function triggers the following middleware.*

```
findOneAndUpdate()
```

**Available options**

- new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the
  original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)
- upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to
  false.
- fields: {Object|String} - Field selection. Equivalent to
  .select(fields).findOneAndUpdate()
- sort: if multiple docs are found by the conditions, sets the sort
  order to choose which doc to update
- maxTimeMS: puts a time limit on the query - requires mongodb >= 2.6.0
- runValidators: if true, runs update validators on this command.
  Update validators validate the update operation against the model's
  schema.
- setDefaultsOnInsert: if this and upsert are true, mongoose will apply
  the defaults specified in the model's schema if a new document is
  created. This option only works on MongoDB >= 2.4 because it relies
  on MongoDB's $setOnInsert operator.
- rawResult: if true, returns the raw result from the MongoDB driver
- context (string) if set to 'query' and runValidators is on, this will
  refer to the query in custom validator functions that update
  validation runs. Does nothing if runValidators is false.

> Callback Signature function(error, doc) {   // error: any errors that
>   occurred   // doc: the document before updates are applied if `new:
>   false`, or after updates if `new = true` }

**Examples**

```
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)  // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback) // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)           // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(update, callback)             // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(update)                       // returns Query
query.findOneAndUpdate(callback)                     // executes
query.findOneAndUpdate()                             // returns Query
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Answer originally added to the question by the author*</sub>

Because Mongoose by default creates a new MongoDB ObjectId ( this hidden _id field) every time you pass it a Javascript Object to update the field of a document.

To go around you can tell Mongoose to not create a new ObjectId, by making sure your mongoose schema is as followed:

**Folder - Models - Stock.js**

> "_id": false - Has to be added to the Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', { useNewUrlParser: true })
const slug = require('slug')


const childSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  date: mongoose.Decimal128,
  open: mongoose.Decimal128,
  high: mongoose.Decimal128,
  low: mongoose.Decimal128,
  close: mongoose.Decimal128,
  volume: mongoose.Decimal128
})

const parentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 4,
    required: 'Plese enter a valid symbol, min 2 characters and max 4'
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [childSchemaData],
  slug: String

});

//we have to PRE-save slug before save the parentSchemaSymbol into DB
parentSchemaSymbol.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('symbol')) {
    next()//skip it
    return//stop this function from running
  }
  this.slug = slug(this.symbol)
  next()
  //TODO make more resiliant soslug are unique
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stock', parentSchemaSymbol)
```